# Android Studio import google api failed

Tags: android, import, google-api

When I set google api at Gradle,

appear an error dialog

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.21.0
```

[image]

---

my classes want to import

```
import com.google.api.client.util.Lists;
```

and

build.Gradle(Module:app) -> dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.21.0'
```

[image]

---

What can I do.

Comment: Try clicking the "Sync with Gradle" button in the toolbar (the Gradle icon next to the SDK Manager button)

Comment: It's work! thanks you all

Answer (score 2):

Update **Google Play Services** from your **android sdk** and try again.