# How do I resolve this Google API dependency issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

[image]
I'm unable to enable the Google Calendar API. I've followed all the instructions present in the Google developer website to the letter. I've tried all the ways possible. I've downloaded all the necessary SDK tools and extra resources but this issue still persists. Please help!

**I've installed Android support repository, Google play services, Google repository. This problem is still there.**

Comment: Did u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805574/android-studio-import-google-api-failed

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes, I've done that, it still isn't working!

Comment: could you show your full gradle file?

Comment: post it then. let's see if we could have something to make right there!

Answer (score 0):

go to setting (or press `Ctrl+Alt+S`) and find `gradle` part then disable  the `Offline work` . after that connect your PC to net and try to sync the `gradle`.

or you can remove all dependencies from `gradle` file (`build.gradle`) and try to add them again . you can see this link  :
[Android Studio with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)

at the end If that not work . you have to download all `lib`s that you added in `compile` section and

add them to your project.

Comment: I've disabled it. It's still not working. Thanks for your input, though!